# Cannot modify files hosted on raspi on other computers in the network

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, samba

I'm having a weird issue with my pi. Pi is set up as SMB host, hosting music files for access around the house. I can't modify the files from any of the other computers though, except with sudo.

I have set all permissions recursively on the whole music collection to 0777.
My smb.conf share is set up thus:

```
[share]
Comment = pi shared folder
Path =/mnt/share
Browseable = yes
Writeable = Yes
only guest = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
public = yes
Guest ok = yes
create mask = 0777
```

If I need to edit a tag, or rename a file, I navigate either in puddletag or nautilus to the file in question, and when I try to edit I get a permission error. If I do either of these things with sudo, however, I can edit freely.

Doing my music maintenance as elevated user is obviously an ok workaround, but a bit annoying. Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

P.S. I'm no pro at this stuff, if I've missed any key info please let me know and I will supply it.

P.P.S The drive I'm sharing is formatted as ext4.

Comment: Did you restart samba after this configuration was saved?

Comment: You've not moved the question only reposted. You should delete one of them.

Comment: It's been configured like this for quite some time, so it's been through numerous shutdown/restart cycles. Also, noted, thanks. I'll delete the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration states only that

```
Guest ok = yes
```

This only allows guest to access the service without password and operate within powers of [the guest account](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#GUESTACCOUNT). But what are they? By default it's `nobody`. Does he have access to your music collection? Remember that if the collection is inside your `/home/you` directory, then even if you set wide open permissions on the collection folder, `nobody` or another user might not even get that far getting stopped by some more restrictive permissions down the way.

Possibly then you just need to overrule the default `nobody` with someone more privileged:

> Default: guest account = nobody # default can be changed at compile-time
>
> Example: guest account = ftp

Or you might move the collection to a more accessible place.

Remember to reload or restart your Samba service after the configuration's been saved.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, I'll look into that. The collection is mounted at /mnt/share, should I move it elsewhere, or was the /home/you comment a caveat rather than a suggestion?

Comment: @Frazbro `/mnt/share` is alright. I'd first check its permissions and then find or create a suitable user. `guest account = that_user`, smb reload and that's it.

Comment: @Frazbro `/home/you` directories are usually private.

Comment: Great, thanks. That's what I thought re     /home/you

Comment: In the end this didn't help, but I changed my fstab on the client computer to mount the share as gues, with UID mask 1000. Previously I had set a username and password and specified them using a file smbcredentials. I gather that the user specified in smbcredentials did not exist/was not added to the right list/had the wrong password. It's now working as desired, although with lower security.